# pdf stamper, pdfEventHandler not working when trying to add page number on the pdf document using itext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, itext

I am using itext to generate a pdf document but I am trying to use the existing solutions to add page number to the pdf document that is being generated but none of them seems to be working for me.

I tried using something like

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
    {
        int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
```

but my code doesnt recognize PdfStamper  and asks me to create a class.
Similarly, I tried using

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
```

There is error on .NumberOfPages and .GetPageSize.

I also tried creating a separate PageEventHandler class but the problem remains same.

Right now, I am able to generate pdf but I want to add page number and I have a code like

```
 private MemoryStream MakeDocument(Application application)
    {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

        using (var document = new Document(pdfDocument))
        {
            var sections = new List<IDocumentSection>
            {
                new Header(),  
                new Projects(application.Projects),                
                //Footer
            };

            foreach (var section in sections)
                section.AddTo(document);

        Rectangle pageSize;
        PdfCanvas canvas;
        int n = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
            pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
            canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
            canvas.BeginText()                    
       .SetFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA), 7)
                .MoveText(pageSize.GetWidth() / 2 - 7, 10)
                .ShowText(i.ToString())
                .ShowText(" of ")
                .ShowText(n.ToString())
                .EndText();
        }
   }
   return ms;
```

---

```
       var outputStream = MakeDocument(application);

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(outputStream.ToArray())
        };

        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        return response;
```

But it is complaining at GetPageSize
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Even if I set page size as A4, it starts to complain at canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using iText 7. Or rather, that's what I assume when I see:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
```

The `PdfStamper` class is an iText 5 class. It doesn't exist in iText 7. See [Chapter 5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document) of the [jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version). You probably want something like this:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
Rectangle pageSize;
PdfCanvas canvas;
int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
    pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
    canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    // draw page numbers on the canvas
}
pdfDoc.close();
```

If you aren't using iText 7, then there's something wrong in your question. In that case you should clarify what you mean when you use the concepts `PdfStamper` and `PdfEventHandler` in the same sentence, because that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right I am using itext7. I am still having some hard time with adding page number.

Comment: Did you read the jump-start tutorial? Adding a header, adding a footer, adding a watermark,... It's all explained in the tutorial. Can you elaborate on what you don't understand?

Comment: I have modified my question, if you could suggest more on that. Yes I did read it but the thing is they are using two separate files.Which is not an issue.But I want to add more sections in the document. SO i cant use the fixed document,

Comment: It is complaining basically at pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

Comment: Which sound does it make when it complains? I don't know if you realize this, but you're not very helpful. It's as if you don't want to be helped. Check [line 113 of the PdfPage class](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7N/repos/itextcore/browse/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/pdf/PdfPage.cs#113). There's a method `GetPageSize()` there, so what are you complaining about? Are you sure you are using the correct `Rectangle` class?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure I am using the right Rectangle class. It is able to recognize the GetPageSize() and when I run my solution then it errors out System.NullReferenceException occurred
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your help... I will work on this problem later

Comment: Are you sure you are working with an *existing* PDF file, and that you're asking for an *existing* page? The code in your question doesn't look like the code I recommended to use.

Comment: I guess so. I am calling the MakeDocument() and inside it I am adding different sections to the document and as soon as I am done adding sections I am adding page number

Comment: Your code will work if I dont have to add sections. I even tried placing the code after var outputStream = MakeDocument(application); but then my outputStream is closed so it doesnt work.

Comment: That's another thing that isn't clear. What do you mean when you say you *have to add section*? What are sections? PDF isn't a word processing format, so you shouldn't expect to be able to insert paragraphs into the existing text. You can insert full pages, but you can't edit a page. That's inherent to PDF. I repeat: **PDF isn't a word processing format.**

Comment: Your question is really confusing. Are you or are you not working with an existing PDF document (which is *always* the case if you require `PdfStamper`). Or are you creating a new PDF from scratch? If you are creating a new PDF from scratch, then why did you start talking about `PdfStamper`? Why would you need a `PdfReader`? You need to clean up your question and be more precise.

Comment: I am creating a new pdf and by sections I mean I am having a list of items that i want to display in pdf ....so i am adding those and then i am creating a document.

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear. You had me all confused because of the fact that you mentioned `PdfStamper` (which is an iText 5 class you only use when you manipulate an existing PDF). Did you read [chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) of the jump-start tutorial? Why not create an `IEventHandler` to add page numbers?